# Prevent resources from being deleted via Terraform/ Azure Console in a large team

Tags: azure, terraform

Current situation: We are at the beginning of a migration to the Azure Cloud. It is an enterprise project with many services. There are several people on the team who have little experience with Terraform or Azure.

Goals:

1. In best case, all resources of the production Azure subscription are managed with Terraform so that changes can be easily tracked and a new empty subscription (e.g. test subscription) can be quickly brought up to the same level. All with as few manual steps as possible.
2. In my absence, changes can also be made by inexperienced team members, but it should be prevented that certain resources are accidentally deleted. In addition, this should also apply to me, since I have not been doing the whole thing for so long and mistakes can always happen. I would like to include several hurdles here to avoid accidental deletion of some resources both on Terraform and in the Azure Gui.

What I have tried:

1.

```
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
```

This prevents deletion using "Terraform destroy" but not, for example, deletion of the resource if someone deletes it from the tf file or deletes the entire ts file and then does "Terraform apply" and then oversees the deletion. It also does not prevent deletion in the Azure Gui.

2. Using azurerm_management_lock

E.g. resource1.tf

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rgtest1" {
  name     = "rgtest1"
  location = "westeurope"
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "azurerm_management_lock" "resource-group-level" {
  name       = "resource-group-level"
  scope      = azurerm_resource_group.rgtest1.id
  lock_level = "CanNotDelete"
  notes      = "This Resource Group should not be deleted"
}
```

Again, doing a general "terraform apply" will not prevent the deletion of the resource if the file is accidentally deleted. Is it possible to keep the lock configuration in another terraform workspace where both workspaces have the same backend and therefore the same terraform state terraform.tfstate?

3. Manually setting the resource lock in the Azure Gui/Console

Since it may be multiple resources and I wanted to keep it as simple as possible, I don't feel this is a really good solution.

4. terraform state rm

I don't like the solution because it should be possible to change the locked resources with Terraform sometimes. In addition, these would be manual commands. It would be better to have this within the Terraform files. Is this possible?

Question:

I must apologize for the complexity of the question. Does anyone have a suggestion in which direction I should go to efficiently prevent accidental deletion (even with owner rights) in a team? Maybe a good "Four eyes principle"?

Comment: Aren't there any security policies in Azure (like IAM at AWS)? You could setup a policy for deployment of the resources, but deny any deletions?

Comment: This would be the management locks. They can be set via terraform azurerm_management_lock or manually.

Comment: The other alternative is to have separate accounts (sorry, I'm taking from AWS perspective). Prod account would have very limited access with strict security, e.g. MFA). The less experience members wouldn't have access to it.

Comment: Yes indeed! but sometimes changes must be done. Even when I am away. My favorite would be something like a four-eyes principle. Do the change and someone else on the team needs to confirm that. Thanks

Comment: I have found a new option. One (!) resource lock at subscription level to prevent any deletion. So you have to first remove this lock.